# Organize a multiuser database website

Tags: php, mysql, database, client

I apologize if this seems overly simple.  I have found it better to ask a dumb question and code things right, than to make a mistake and spend hours and hours trying to find it and fix it.

I made my brother a client management system (PHP / MYSQL) a few of his friends saw it and want one too.  So I thought it would be a good idea to just make a single website where each person has their own login/password.  When they log in to their account they see only their database of clients.  That sounds like a great idea, but I am hitting a mental roadblock.

Right now on my brother's site I have one database with two tables one for login info (so he can give access to his team), and then the actual database holding all of the client information.  If I followed this model I would still only need one database with one table for login information, but each user would have to have their own table for their individual clients.  So say I get more and more users eventually I have a single database with a hundred(s) different tables.  Is that okay? Are their security issues? Is there a better way to go about this?  Am I missing some logic?  Thanks.

Comment: keep all your sql in source control. use scripts to create/patch the databases. use one database per tenant (mysql databases aren't actually databases in the common nomenclature, they are schemas)

Answer (score 1):

> If I followed this model I would still only need one database with one table for login information, but each user would have to have their own table for their individual clients.

No. You have a single clients table. One of the columns in it will be a [foreign key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_key) that references the primary key of the user table (showing to which user a client is associated).

(Unless one client can be associated with multiple users, in which case you would use a [junction table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Junction_table)).

Comment: I like it! I would imagine my sql query would have a lot to do with this, but is there any security vulnerability I need to be sure to watch for to keep other users from seeing clients they didn't add.  I can't think of a scenario off the top of my head, but having all the clients mixed in together just makes me nervous!

Comment: Yes. When any user requests information about a client, check that that client belongs to that user.

Comment: something like: SELECT * FROM clients WHERE userid=1 AND whatever data I want to find

Answer (score 0):

Well at the beginnig you can implement a table called Client or Company (all your clients have to enter a row in that table, I mean your brother and any other guy/company who/which want to use your website), and the PK from the table should be added in all the tables in your DB.

But what will happen if you website rocks? Maybe 10000 clients you have, you should analize if the performance of the server (maybe the hosting) support that kind of rate transfer and also the PKs/FKs are working ok. In that time, maybe you should create a DB and a website for each client you have.